# ASP.NET Core 5 WebAPI gives 404 not found error

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

We have a very simple ASP.NET Core 5 Web API written in C#. Works fine on the dev machine and on the test server.

Our Get Method simply returns a string value.

1. We installed .NET hosting 5.0.11 bundle on Test Server.
2. Created an App Pool (not managed) with service account as Identity
3. Created Web App in IIS 10 with App Pool and HTTP binding port 99

It works fine on the Test server. But when we follow the same steps on Production then I keep getting 404 not found error.

I even tried the default `WeatherForecast` API. Even that is throwing same 404 not found error in Production.

Here are contents of `web.config` and `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs`:

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MVATest.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: f6bd6db8-d217-4d15-b1d3-06388fe80490-->
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MVATest", Version = "v1" });
        });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MVATest v1"));
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Comment: I notice you have defined a Swagger endpoint and a Swagger UI. Are you able to access them... Or is everything giving you a 404 error?

Comment: Its questions like this that remind me why I love Docker.. I digress. It could be 10's of reasons why - have you checked your Event Viewer for exceptions? IIS "normally/sometimes" sticks something useful in there if it falls over

Comment: Update: Sorry. it was not 404. it was 400 Bad Request. I followed this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/troubleshooting-http-400-errors-in-iis to check http log and noticed "400 - Hostname" with our request log.

Then I removed the hostname from the IIS SiteBinding window. That resolved the issue. API is accessible with IP address. Still investigating that why we are getting issues with a hostname.